# Не выводит value hidden через method get

Tags: php, html, hidden

У меня есть такой код:

```
if (count($out) > 0) {
    $func = pagination($posts = []);
    echo count($func);
    $counter_times = 0;
    $page_num = 1;
    foreach ($out as $row) {
        $counter_times++;

?>
        <div style="margin:10px; padding:5px;width:450px;background:f0f0f0;">
            <div style="color: #999999; border-bottom:1px solid #999999;padding:5px;">Опубликовал: <span style="color: #444;font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></span></div>
            <div style="background:#fafafa;padding:5px;"><?php echo $row['message']; ?></div>
            <div style="color: #999999; border-top:1px solid #999999;padding:5px;">Дата публикации: <?php echo $row['date']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    }
    if ($counter_times === 5) {
        echo "<form action=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . " method='get'>
        <input type='submit' value='>' name='next' />
        <input type='hidden' value=" . $page_num . " name='page' />
        </form>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Пока что нет новостей...<br>";
}
echo "</div>";

if (isset($_GET['next'])) {
    $page_num = $_GET['page'];
    $page_num++;
}
```

Я хочу вывести значение $page_num, которое с каждым разом должно увеличиваться. Но мне пишет Undefined array key "page". То есть программа почему-то не видит input type='hidden'

Comment: Судя по ошибке, она возникает здесь `$_GET['page']`. Видимо нет такого get параметра

Comment: Нет, этот праметр есть "<form action=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . " method='get'>
        <input type='submit' value='>' name='next' />
        <input type='hidden' value=" . $page_num . " name='page' />
        </form>";

Comment: а в URL вы этот параметр видите? На сколько я помню, `hidden` не передается в `get` запросах, только в `post`

Comment: Да, вижу. У меня были раньше примеры hidden с get